# Identify what kind of lime tree I have!

Tags: trees, fruit-trees

I have 3 of these on my property.  They were here when my parents bought the property in 1974.  They are not Kaffir limess because the do not have the double leaves.  The fruit are mostly small and medium in size with very rough bumpy skin.  Very juicy, many seeds, tastes is excellent lime flavor!  Pulp is whitish to clear.  Any ideas?  Thanks.  Oh, I live in Miami![image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Nice picture, and it is definitely a "lime". The fruit looks very similar to the Australian native lime - **Citrus australis** - but the leaves in your photo look somewhat different from these as well. Kaffir limes (**Citrus hystrix**) often have a "neck" on the fruit while the Australian lime is round.  Both have tough wrinkled skin. Most citrus species hybridize readily. Perhaps it is a hybrid between these two (or Kaffir with another citrus). Almost all commercial citrus are hybrids of some kind.

https://alchetron.com/Citrus-australis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaffir_lime

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrus